# Where does SMS backup on WP8 actually back up to? Is it user accessible?

Tags: 8.0, sms, backup

I have SMS backup turned on, and it should sync to the outlook.com account I've used to set up the phone (it's a gmail login though) Does it store it somewhere I can see old sms messages, or is it just not working? (I can't see my sms anywhere)

Comment: I'm still waiting for my 8.0 device to arrive, but have you checked SkyDrive (as that's where Windows Mobile 6.5 used to back up to)

Comment: Yes, checked skydrive, and outlook.com

Answer (score 3):

Based on tweets with Microsoft Windows Phone Support, it is currently impossible to see the backups, or to know that they are there.

https://twitter.com/WinPhoneSupport/status/269556758165467137