# Can I back up text messages onto OneDrive AND delete them from my phone, Nokia Lumia 810?

Tags: onedrive, storage, sms, backup

Is it possible to backup my text messages onto the OneDrive AND delete these messages from my phone?  I need space on my phone, Nokia Lumia 810, but I don't want to completely delete my messages from all existence (for sentimental value).  So I don't want these messages to be restored to my phone ever, I just want them saved somewhere.  Or else, is there a Windows app that can store text messages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I export or extract my text messages to a file?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/how-can-i-export-or-extract-my-text-messages-to-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

When you delete the texts on your phone they will be deleted from your backup as well! 
Deleting text messages will also not free up a lot of space. I'd recommend getting a (bigger) MicroSD card for your phone.

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/back-up-my-stuff

Answer (score 0):

Messages in backup will get deleted once the messages in phone are deleted too.

> I don't want these messages to be restored to my phone ever, I just
>   want them saved somewhere.

In that case you can export your messages to a file and save the files somewhere(even in OneDrive) manually. Microsoft has published 2 apps namely [Transfer my Data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/transfer-my-data/9wzdncrfj3dr) and [contacts+messages backup](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/contacts-message-backup/9NBLGGGZ57GM).

You can find more details here : [How can I export or extract my text messages to a file?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/how-can-i-export-or-extract-my-text-messages-to-a-file)

Answer (score -2):

yeah absolutely you can sync your texts back them up to onedrive and delete them from your phone.
when you update your phone your phone also deletes all the texts and then restores the texts,app settings,notes even every call logs.

Comment: The Lumia 810 runs Windows Phone 8, not 7.