# Open and process SMS in ZUNE like it was done Nokia PC SUite

Tags: sms, zune

I frequently use SMS messages to control some SMS interface control/alarm/measurement instrument. With the old Nokia PC Suite it was possible to download SMS messages to a PC and even use the PC to send SMS's through a connected phone. I found this very useful. With new Nokia phone models (N9 and onwards) this functionality has disappeared bit-by-bit. First the possibility to send SMS's disappeared, then new Lumia phones were not supported by PC Suite.

Is it possible to get SMS's to a PC using Zune? Preferably control SMS's similar to how PC Suite did.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/2070/106

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to download, backup, modify or work with SMS / texts in any way using the Zune software. Zune can only be used to move music, pictures, podcasts and videos to **Windows Phone 7.X** devices.

There's also no other software that would allow such kind of access as Microsoft has not yet opened up any APIs for developers to use.

Comment: How do you know he doesn't have a WP7 device?

Comment: I don't. I just wanted to emphasize that Zune is only relevant for WP7 devices as he specifically asked about it - however there are a lot of people that don't realize Zune doesnt work with Windows Phone 8+.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't allow *sending* them, there is one way to access backed-up SMS on WP8.x. The process is described in [this answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/11578/15445), but in essence it involves using Outlook.com, enabling some categories that aren't usually visible, and there you will see your backed-up SMS and MMS.

On rooted WP7 phones, there's a SMS backup app available on XDA-Developers. For WP8, it's possible to use the "Transfer My Data" app to back up SMS to your PC.