# Get all the text messages(SMSs) on my phone as a file on my computer

Tags: lumia, sms, 7.8, messaging

I have a Nokia Lumia 710 which is running Windows Phone 7.8. I would like to get all the text messages I have on my phone as a text file on my computer.

There seems to be solution for phones running Windows Phone 8 here,
[How can I export or extract my text messages to a file?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/how-can-i-export-or-extract-my-text-messages-to-a-file)

But, most of what I found on the Internet is deeply disheartening. Many claim that this is impossible. Some of the sources I went through are,


https://superuser.com/questions/307946/windows-phone-7-how-to-download-sms-text-messages-to-disk

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=999376

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1072796

Please note that I am running Windows 7.8 and NOT 7.

One way I could think up is to make a video of the phone's screen scrolling through all the messages and use text detection on the video. Is there any other less time consuming way ?

I am open to doing lots of work for this. I tried to access the storage through a Linux(Ubuntu) machine as well, without much success. I am open to using 3rd party tools as well. If nothing else works, I am also open to methods which can cause damage to my phone.

Thanks !

---

### **EDIT**

This is **not** a duplicate of [How can I export or extract my text messages to a file?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/how-can-i-export-or-extract-my-text-messages-to-a-file) , because this question is specifically for Windows Phone 7.8. Which is considerably different from Windows Phone 8.

Comment: This is not a duplicate because this question is meant only for windows phone 7.8 and NOT 8, which is very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a few sources on Microsoft Answers, there is currently no app on the marketplace to do this nor 'built in' support for this on Windows Phone 7.8.

Sources:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wppeople/windows-7-phone-how-to-save-text-messages/05eff4fa-1645-e011-90b6-1cc1de79d2e2

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wppeople/how-can-i-export-backup-archive-sms-in-nokia-lumia/c6c51904-4456-4e87-9879-3371e552b5f5