# Saving messages to a file

Tags: nokia-lumia-1020

How did you do this on your lumia 1020? that is what I have, but am having trouble figuring out how to do it. I see the name of the app but cannot find it in the store or on my phone. I would like to save texts for legal reasons so it is important. I would like to save them to my computer once they are in a file so I can have them once I get a new phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/2070/106

Comment: Doesn't turning on message syncing work for you? ("..so I can have them once I get a new phone.")

Answer (score 4):

[contacts+messages backup](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/contacts-message-backup/9nblgggz57gm) app can be used to store the messages for transferring to other Windows phones.

1. This app will be located in Settings. Hence go to *`Settings->Contacts + messages backup`*.
2. Now select backup option.
   [image: Welcome screen of the app]
3. Select SMS, MMS or Contacts and click backup.
   [image: Selection screen]
4. You can restore the backup from an another phone.

Note : The app will recover backups only if it is present in the folder named 'backup+restore' on the SD card.

Known Issue: Restoring a backup of messages from a dual SIM Windows Phone restores all messages to message store for the first SIM/slot.

Comment: It may be worth expanding your answer to include steps of how to use this to export the messages to a file

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's app [**Transfer my Data**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Transfer-my-Data/9WZDNCRFJ3DR) helps you to backup you data to SD card and later import from the backup on an another phone.

**Note :**

- This application will restore your messages correctly in Dual SIM phones (some apps restore all messages in SIM1).
- This application will also restore your contacts will their contact pics.

**Steps** :

To create a backup follow these steps :

1. Open the app
2. Click on the menu (3 dots ...) at the right side bottom.

[image: Menu(pivot) icon]

3. Click on the `Export to SD card option`.

[image: Export to SD card option]

4. Now select Contacts, Text messages and MMS (whichever is required). And click next.

[image: Selection menu]

5. Now you will see the progress in the screen. This usually takes a minute or too.

[image: Progress screen]

6. Once the backup is complete you will see a screen with a the location of the backup.

[image: Final screen]