# Transfer contact to my sim card

Tags: 8.1, contacts, transfer, sim

I have a Microsoft account but I have forgotten my password and I now need to reset my mobile.

How can I transfer my contacts from my windows phone 435 to another mobile or to my sim card?

Comment: https://drfone.wondershare.com/transfer/how-to-transfer-contacts-from-lumia-to-android.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer your contacts to your sim card as of now. However you can use the [Transfer My data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/transfer-my-data/9wzdncrfj3dr) app by Microsoft to transfer your contacts to another phone or take a backup to SD card.

You can find step by step instructions in [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12565/18061)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Transfer my Data** app to transfer contacts to your sd card and then import them in other phone(If your device is out for service for long duration) or else just keep it in your sd card.

If you want to import contacts from other devices to your windows phone, and if there are a lot of them than also you can use the transfer my data app!
Have a look at [this Link](https://youthhworld.blogspot.com/2016/08/transfer-contacts-from-sim-or-old-phone.html)